# How can I add a custom variable to Sqitch, to be used in Snowflake change scripts?

Tags: sqitch

I'd like to define a custom variable called `task_warehouse` to be used in a Snowflake change script, like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK dummy_task
    WAREHOUSE = &task_warehouse
    SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
    AS
        SELECT 1;
```

The task warehouse is different from `&warehouse`. I want the task warehouse to vary depending on the `DATABASE` being deployed to. I don't want to change the warehouse that's running the deploy script.

I tried adding `;task_warehouse=<WAREHOUSE_NAME>` to the Snowflake connection string, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

I get this error when trying to deploy:

```
Variable task_warehouse is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to define a custom variable to be used by Sqitch, similar to how `&warehouse` is used in the following?

```sql
USE WAREHOUSE &warehouse;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues was able to figure it out. It says under the "variables" bullet towards the bottom of https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitch-configuration/.

Example from that page:

```sh
sqitch deploy --set $key=$val -s $key2=$val2
```

Doing the following worked for me:

```sh
sqitch deploy -s task_warehouse=PROD_TASK_WAREHOUSE
```